# Как добавить 4 часа к дате в гугл таблице?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет. У меня есть несколько вопросов по работе с регулярными выражениями и датами в гугл таблицах.

Допустим в ячейку гугл-таблицы вводится дата (штамп даты) в таком виде:
`2019-02-16T22:14:15.339Z`

1. Как с помощью регулярного выражения (я так понимаю нужно использовать функцию `REGEXEXTRACT`) преобразовать в формат: `2019-02-16 22:14:15` ?
2. После этого к дате `2019-02-16 22:14:15` нужно добавить 4 часа. Как это сделать в гугл таблице? Если я правильно понимаю, сначала нужно перевести значение `2019-02-16 22:14:15` в формат `Продолжительность/Duration`. Добавить 4 часа (04:00:00). А потом вернуть формат нормальной даты. Но как это реализовать с помощью гугл формул???

Вообщем, нужна ваша помощь. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вам на выходе нужна дата или текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формулы

- B2 - `=SPLIT(A2; "T.Z"; TRUE; TRUE)`
- F2 - `=B2+C2+(E2/24)`

update

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- B2 - `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2;"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")+REGEXEXTRACT(A2;"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")+4/24`
- B2 - задаем формат - `Формат-> Числа -> Дата и Время`

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Уже гораздо лучше. 
А как сделать, чтобы эти все вычисления происходили в одной клетке?
Т.е., буквально в одной ячейке есть строка "2019-02-16T22:14:15.339Z", а в следующей происходят все нужные вычисления.

Comment: @Andrey: добавлять вы всегда именно 4 часа будете?

Comment: да, это значение всегда будет константой.

Comment: @Andrey: схлопнуть колонки никак? Или вынести ячейки что вам не нужны за область видимости?

Comment: @Andrey: просто перенесите колонку за шапку ближе к нужной колонке, формула не сбивается. Остальные или схлопнуть или тоже перетащить с глаз долой

Comment: дело в том, что я получаю с помощью автоматизатора Zapier временной штамп такого типа "2019-02-16T22:14:15.339Z". Далее автоматизатору нужно ввести в ячейку гугл-таблицы формулу с этой строкой, которая преобразует её в дату + 4 часа.

Comment: @Andrey: обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Немного помучался и нашел такой вариант:

```
=ТЕКСТ(ТЕКСТ(ЗАМЕНИТЬ(ЗАМЕНИТЬ("2019-02-16T22:14:15.339Z",11,1," "),20,5,""), "[hh]:mm:ss")+ТЕКСТ("04:00:00", "[hh]:mm:ss"), "DD.MM")
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно грубо добавлять 0,167 к 2019-02-16 22:14:15

A1 = 2019-02-16 22:14:15
B1 = A1+0,167

Увеличив число значений после запятой, получим более точный результат.

Answer (score 0):

разбить
2019-02-16T22:14:15.339Z
на
2019-02-16 22:14:15 --можно с помощью формул left и mid

привести столбец с 2019-02-16 в формат date
привести столбец с 22:14:15 в формат time
в доп столбце просто складываем два значения =date+time
приводим в формат дата и время, должно получится "2019-02-16 22:14:15"

в дополнительный столбец копируем любое значение из колонки time и приводим к 04:00:00

складываем значения "2019-02-16 22:14:15"+ "04:00:00"
ко времени прибавляются часы и дата соответственно меняется

Answer (score 0):

когда к дате прибавляем единицу - прибавляется 24 часа, следовательно 1/24*4 прибавляем эту цифру к дате - получаем +4 часа